# Automate keyboard input in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, automation

How to perform keyboard or mouse automation from bash script on Ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to add 'Alt+Tab' keyboard input automation to bash script on every 5 second.

getting error.

> ./test.sh: line 3: `gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")'

anyone has idea other then using python, please share.

Comment: It looks like you put python code inside of your bash script. Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: yes, but that is not working as expected. do you have any simpler idea for this @jordanm

Comment: What's unexpected about bash not executing code intended for a different language?